# Configure HTTP server to access the deployments on 2 cluster members

Tags: apache, tomcat, configuration, cluster-computing, multicast

I have created 2 tomcat 7 servers and an apache httpd server.

The apache server is on the same IP address `10.x.x.1` with **tomcat one**. 
**Tomcat two** is on `10.x.x.2`. 
I use the multicast address in **server.xml** by default, which is `228.0.0.4`.

I've succeeded to use **FarmWarDeployer** to deploy to both of the tomcats. I did move `<Cluster>` block under `<Host>` and had to copy *.war* files to `watchDir`. I put some information about the configuration files here :

**server.xml** :

```
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="worker1">
  <!-- something here ignored -->
  <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
    <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster" channelSendOptions="8">

      <Manager className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager"
               expireSessionsOnShutdown="false"
               notifyListenersOnReplication="true"/>
          <Channel className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.GroupChannel">
            <!-- something here ignored -->
            <Membership className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastService"
                        address="228.0.0.4"
                        port="45564"
                        frequency="500"
                        dropTime="3000"/>
         </Channel>
         <!-- something here ignored -->
         <Deployer className="org.apache.catalina.ha.deploy.FarmWarDeployer"
                    tempDir="/tmp/war-temp/"
                    deployDir="/webapps/"
                    watchDir="/tmp/war-listen/"
                    watchEnabled="true"/>
   </Cluster>
 </Host>
</Engine>
```

**worker.properties** :

```
# Define worker names
worker.list=jkstatus,loadbalancer

# Create loadbalancer workers
worker.jkstatus.type=status
worker.loadbalancer.type=lb

# Declare Tomcat server workers
worker.worker1.type=ajp13
worker.worker1.host=10.x.x.1
worker.worker1.port=8009
worker.worker1.lbfactor=1

worker.worker2.type=ajp13
worker.worker2.host=10.x.x.2
worker.worker2.port=9009
worker.worker2.lbfactor=1

# Associate workers with loadbalancer worker
worker.loadbalancer.balanced_workers=worker1,worker2
worker.loadbalancer.sticky_session=1
```

My first problem here is, before moving `<Cluster>` under `<Host>`, the URL of httpd server (`10.x.x.1:9060`) could lead me to the console of **tomcat one**. Then after that, maybe some more other modifications in **server.xml**, the same URL can just display **It works!**.

My second question is, how can we define the multicast address? As the IPs of my machines are like `10.x.x.x`. Should I modify the multicast address to adapt them?

My third question is once the URL of httpd server could lead to the console of tomcat. How can we just use the console to deploy *war* files to both of the tomcats, not through copying them to `watchDir`.

And my last question is should I `JKMount` all the applications to loadbalancer? There is a war file is the main product, and the other wars are based on it. How exactly we could verify that working status of loadbalancer?

That's a lot of questions... I sincerely appreciate in advance of your responses...

Allen

Comment: Please, someone could give me a hint, thanks !

Comment: @PaulSweatte Hi, thanks for your answer, but I do not think so.... I already implement the solution mentioned on that thread. Mine is maybe about how to configure http server to access the deployments on the 2 cluster members

Comment: Could someone please remove the head line of my post? Guys with answers could see that and go away. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @allenzzzxd did you find a solution?